# Find latest entries in a list based on a field

Tags: grails, findby

I'm not even sure how to search if this is an existing questions. Let me just give an example:

```
Call Instance   Date Created           Resource    Resource Status
------------------------------------------------------------------
6557            2013-07-12 11:34:19    cwood       Accepted
6556            2013-07-12 11:34:18    cwood       Accepted
                2013-07-12 11:29:25    cwood       Ready
6555            2013-07-12 09:24:41    cwood       Accepted
```

How do I get the top two Accepted entries off the top  without getting the last Accepted entry (as it came before a Ready entry)?

All the fields except for Date Created are user-defined classes (Call, User [no, not Resource], and ResourceStatus).

Please let me know if further code would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Micha, still new to actually asking questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`takeWhile()`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#takeWhile%28groovy.lang.Closure%29):

```
​assert [1,2] == [1,2,3,4,5].takeWhile { it < 3 }​
```

**EDIT**(*Audacity of @dmahapatro  to edit answer*)
Small test case for available statuses other than Accepted and Ready:

```
def list = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'R', 'A']
assert list.takeWhile{ it == 'A'} == ['A', 'A']
assert list.takeWhile{ it != 'R'} == ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: Whoaaaaa.  I knew there would be something Groovier than looping through it!  Time to check it out.

Comment: Boom! Like magic!  For future answer seekers, I grabbed about 10 ResourceHistory's off the top of the table and fed them into takeWhile with the test of statusDescription == "Accepted".  It only gave me the first 2, exactly as needed. Thanks again @doelleri!

Comment: @CharlesWood Will you only have `Accepted` and `Ready` statuses available? Your approach is correct in that case. But if you have more statuses and you want all the `Accepted` statuses before `Ready` then you have to use `statusDescription != 'Ready'`. See the update above.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point @dmahapatro. Occasionally a user may go Busy while working on a call, and I'll want to get any Accepted statuses that occur before the Busy but after the Ready ("before" being "to the right of"), AND not get the Busy either. So, I suppose I'll need to do `statusDescription != 'Ready' and statusDescription != 'Busy'` or so.  Code sure would be a lot cleaner without people having to use it!

Comment: @dmahapatro -- nope, that still only gets the first 2 `A`s.  Any idea how to get 3 `A`s out of the above list?

Comment: Eh, I'll just have them go back into Busy state if they are Busy when they log out.  It's more consistent anyway.

Comment: @CharlesWood I tried something anyways. :) Thought I would post it as answer (no obligation for votes :) ) for better formatting instead of posting as comment.

Answer (score 1):

Logic for the below problem statement:

*Oh, that's a good point @dmahapatro. Occasionally a user may go Busy while working on a call, and I'll want to get any Accepted statuses that occur before the Busy but after the Ready ("before" being "to the right of"), AND not get the Busy either. So, I suppose I'll need to do statusDescription != 'Ready' and statusDescription != 'Busy' or so. Code sure would be a lot cleaner without people having to use it!*

```
def list = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'R', 'A', 'A','B', 'A']

def statusBeforeBusy = list.takeWhile{ it != 'B'}
println "Statuses before Busy: $statusBeforeBusy" //[A, A, A, R, A, A]

def statusBeforeReady = list.takeWhile{ it != 'R'}
println "Statuses before Ready: $statusBeforeReady" //[A, A, A]

def statusaAfterReadyBeforeBusy = statusBeforeBusy.dropWhile{ it != 'R'}.tail()
println "Statuses After Ready before Busy: $statusaAfterReadyBeforeBusy" //[A, A]
```

Comment: Well, as I said, I'm just to get everything to the left of the 'R'. Thanks for the code though, this is still Groovier than a for loop or something.